# Change value of array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code:

```
List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();
// Convert to 2D array
String[][] dataArr = new String[list.size()][];
```

Now I want to replace some char at specific values.

```
dataArr = list.toArray(dataArr);
String help = Arrays.toString(dataArr[0]).replace("[", "");
dataArr[0] = help;
```

But I get this error:

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]

My question is, how can I fix this?

Edit:

Wow, thanks for all the input.

I have to be a little bit more specific and this is my input file:

> [0,0,0,1,1]
>
> [1,1,1,1,1]
>
> [0,0,0,0,0]
>
> [1,0,1,0,1]
>
> [0,1,0,1,0]

This line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dataArr));
```

leads to following output:

> [[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]], [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]]

I want to replace the double "[[" and "]]" to "[" and "]".

Comment: you should use dataArr[][] while calling replace()  because it is a 2-D array

Comment: It does not work because you just converted your `dataArr` to a 2D Array. So basically, you will have to do `dataArr[0][0]` to get the first element.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: @NicoHoppel, I edited my answer to match your edited question. My answer now replaces the double "[[" to a single "[" and also for the other bracket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to replace all the "`[[`" you can simply use

```
String output = Arrays.deepToString(dataArr);
output = output.replaceAll("\\[\\[","\\[");
output = output.replaceAll("\\]\\]","\\]");
output = output.substring(2, output.length()-2);
String[] matrix = output.split("\\],\\[");
```

And that should do it

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 1
[[
Thanks, perfect idea, but I get this error..

Comment: oops. just a second

Comment: @NicoHoppel, how about now?

Comment: Now I have a String, but I need an array instead. Is it possible to split the string like this :
String[] matrix  = output.split();

Answer (score 1):

dataArr is a 2D array of string. You are trying to assign help String to a dataArr[0] which is array of string. You have to specify second index eg

```
dataArr[0][0] = help;
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataArr` is of type String[][]

You can't assign string to it using

```
dataArr[0] = help;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataArr[0] = help;
```

This is your issue. It could be resolved with:

```
dataArr[0][0] = help;
```